# Why is my nested while loop not working

Tags: python, nested, while-loop

Working on a program in python to print out the first 1000 prime numbers (except 2). all i can get for the output is the number 3. don't understand where or when my loop is ending. very new at programming. can anybody help?

```
primeCounter = 1
candidate = 3

while primeCounter < 1000:
    isPrime = True
    counter = 2
    while counter < candidate:
        if candidate%counter == 0:
            isPrime = False
        else:
            counter = counter + 1

    if isPrime == True:
        print candidate
        primeCounter = primeCounter + 1

     candidate = candidate + 1
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it at all? perhaps by having it output the values of the variables that are tested for conditionals and so forth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
primeCounter = 1
candidate = 3

while primeCounter < 1000:
    isPrime = True
    counter = 2
    while counter < candidate:
        if candidate%counter == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   break here, or the loop will go infinite
        else:
            counter = counter + 1

    if isPrime == True:
        print candidate
        primeCounter = primeCounter + 1

    candidate = candidate + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you set `isPrime` to `False`, you never increment `counter` again, so you never get out of the inner `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in block

```
while counter < candidate:
    if candidate%counter == 0:
        isPrime = False
```

if not candidate % counter, you get infinity loop.